# Mariadb configuration is not loaded from my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf, mysqld

My mariadb configuration in my.cnf is not getting loaded for `"log-error"` and `"pid-file"`. I have checked other configurations params are loaded.

```
[root@kvm10 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
!includedir /etc/mysqld/conf.d
datadir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql_tmp
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
### TRT-3229 #####
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa = 1
myisam_repair_threads = 2
myisam_recover_options = FORCE
###################
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache=256
max_heap_table_size=256M
### TRT-4685 ###
max_connections=500
################
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[root@kvm10 ~]#
```

But the configuration value for `log-error` & `pid-file` is not picked by MariaDB.

```
[root@kvm10 ~]# mysql -e "show variables like 'pid_file'"
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                             |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| pid_file      | /mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql/kvm10.pid |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
[root@kvm10 ~]# mysql -e "show variables like 'log_error'"
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_error     |       |
+---------------+-------+
[root@kvm10 ~]#
```

Am I missing somethig or making some mistake. I have checked the files permissions in `/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log` & `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`.

Comment: Try moving `log-error` to the `[mysqld]` section of the configuration file

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem in `~/.my.cnf` file (`MySQL 5.5.5-10.2.6-MariaDB` installed via Homebrew).

Apparently it is a recorded bug in both MySQL and MariaDB:

**Bug #84172    The pid-file value is ignored in the /etc/my.cnf option file**
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84172

**pid_file in my.cnf ignored**
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8168

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is some default behaviour of Mariadb or lack of our knowledge to figure how Mariadb picks its my.cnf.

I have worked to resolve similar issue and made mysqld_safe to point to the my.cnf that we want to pick it, in below fashion.

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf &
```

**Reference Issue :** [Mariadb - Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173789/mariadb-variable-innodb-log-file-size-is-a-read-only-variable/173794#173794)

**Reference Chat:** 
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58883/discussion-between-mannoj-and-bhuvanesh