# Mariadb - Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, log

Im using mariadb **10.0.29**, I need to change the innodb file size to 256M, default size 50M,

My config file is located on

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

I have added the below line, but it won't work.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size=256M
```

Also I tried `set innodb_log_file_size=5033164800;`

But it shows

```
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have to consider two things before doing this.

1. Ensure innodb_fast_shutdown SHOULDN'T BE 2. If it is? change it
   to 1 globally.
2. Verify  step 1, query: `show variables like 'innodb_fast_shutdown';`
3. Shutdown Mysql.
4. Ensure you copy the iblogfile0&1 into a safer place and then
   remove from data dir.
5. Make changes to my.cnf for innodb_log_file_size as per your
   desired option.
6. Start Mysql

*Rollback: If it doesn't start for some reason put back the iblogfiles and start.*

Please see link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html for detailed explanation

> UPDATE: In our chat we narrowed down that my.cnf was pointed to a
>   different file or picked default ones. We forced mysql to pick the
>   mentioned my.cnf via mysqld_safe --defaults-file. And it worked.

Comment: I tried this Mannoj, but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58883/discussion-between-mannoj-and-bhuvanesh).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the option innodb_log_group_home_dir

1

```
[root@]# mkdir /var/mysqltest
[root@]# chown mysql:mysql /var/mysqltest
```

2

```
[root@]# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

> innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/mysqltest
>
> innodb_log_file_size=256M

3

```
[root@]# service mariadb  restart
```

That's all